# Earth Engine: Equidistant Buffer

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer, equal-length

Is there a way to make an equidistant buffer in Earth Engine for a **globally-distributed** set of geometries?

For example, if there's a single point, we can provide an EPSG code of a corresponding equidistant projection as a `prj` argument to a `.buffer()` method, but if there are multiple points that are distibuted across the globe, I guess a single equidistant projection won't help.

Is there a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do it for one point, you can simply map that operation over all points, using a different projection for each one.

But buffer already uses a spherical coordinate system (and units of meters) if you don't specify a projection, so I don't think you need to mess with projections at all.